# I am running Windows 10, can I download and install BIOS of Windows 8?

Tags: windows, laptop, bios, fan, overheating

My fan is not operating correctly (it runs quite even at 70 degree C = 158 degree F). My laptop seems to have no software or drivers for Windows 10 (mine is Enterprise LTSB 2016) from the manufacturer HP, I have installed Windows 10 without knowing about the problems.

I don't know whether updated BIOS can fix the fan issue or not. Before that, can I install [BIOS of windows 8 from the manufacturer](https://support.hp.com/in-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-pavilion-g6-2200-notebook-pc-series/5296082/model/5340269/swItemId/ob-174272-1), while running windows 10?

For more detailed description: [See this discussion](https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/how-to-configure-speedfan/)

Edit (30/8/17): I used "Reset This PC" option in Windows 10; in the process of resetting, while installing drivers, at certain percentage, fan started running! It is running now, I don't know whether it would continue or not.
Thank you everyone.

Comment: The BIOS is not operating system dependent. If you can, and you should be able to, download and run the BIOS installation file on Windows 10 it will be fine.  Your fan running quiet at 70 degrees on a laptop is actually not that unusual. Some laptops run up to 80 or 90 degrees or more before really kicking in. I don't agree with that necessarily, but it's true.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. From the BIOS update page (given in the post): "The update installs on supported notebook models using a supported Microsoft Windows Operating System."...editing

Comment: The text is saying *supported Microsoft Windows*, I am thinking whether update will be installed through W10 or not.

Comment: It will be fine. Please try.

Comment: Thank you, then I can install that BIOS version. Do you think it will solve the fan issue?

Comment: I have checked [BIOS update details](https://support.hp.com/in-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-pavilion-g6-2200-notebook-pc-series/5296082/model/5340269/swItemId/ob-174272-1), it seems to be not explicit in what it fixes.

Comment: Any Windows 10 driver will work for 1607 which is the version you are running.